# How to retrieve Failed Iterations SQL

Tags: sql

I have Data like following

```
ID Value
1  Failed
1  Failed
1  Failed
1  Passed
1  Failed
2  Failed
2  Failed
2  Failed
2  Failed
2  Failed
```

I want to retrieve IDs for only Failed Iterations using SQL. How Can I Do it?

Comment: Do you know how to write a basic `select`/`from`/`where` statement?

Comment: Yes I know. Retrieving only Failed Iterations same ID? How to Do?

Comment: So in this case you want only 2 as output correct?

Comment: Yes. I tried using Distinct Word, but it checks only for First ID.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to return those `ids` where *all* `values` are equal to `failed`.

If so, you can use `group by`:

```
select id
from yourtable
group by id
having count(*) = sum(case when value = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
select distinct a1.ID from B as a1
left join B as a2 on a1.id = a2.id  
                and a2.value <> 'failed'
where a1.value = 'failed'
    and a2.ID is null
```

Although this will provide correct result, I have used join, but answer of @sgeddes looks dam good!

Comment: Yes..Thanks...Both Simple soutions